Switch context to webview is failed in hybrid mobile application automation using webdriveIO
I am trying setup webview automation for my app which is running in Android and iOS devices as a hybrid application(written in react native0
While running my automation code
I am trying to switch webview using
      const webviewName = `WEBVIEW_${packageName}`;
      await driver.switchContext(webviewName);

In Android 14 devices, its switching to webview and doing next line work as expected.
When i run the same again in Android 13, 15 devices, its fails to switch to webview context even though webview is alive my device.
I took this code from github
        /**
         * Custom implementation to switch to a webview for Android and iOS
         */
              async switchToContext({ context, title, url }: { context: ContextType, title?: string, url?: string }) {
            if (context === CONTEXT_REF.NATIVE_APP) {
                return driver.switchContext(CONTEXT_REF.NATIVE_APP);
            }

            // Title and url are optional, but if they are provided we can use them to find the correct webview.
            // We can't only rely on the context name due to the fact that we can have multiple webviews which
            // could have different titles/urls
            if (!title && !url) {
                console.warn('\nTo get the best result, provide a title and, or url which will be used to find the correct webview. The more information the bigger the chance it will find the correct webview.\n');
            }

            // Get the contexts with our custom method
            const currentContexts = await this.getCurrentContexts();

            let matchingContext;
            let packageName;

            // This is where the magic happens, we are going to find the correct context(pae) to switch to for iOS or Android.
            if (driver.isIOS) {
                matchingContext = this.findMatchingContext({ contexts: currentContexts, identifier: BUNDLE_ID, title, url });
            } else {
                packageName = await driver.getCurrentPackage();
                // 1. To find the correct webview page for Android we need to switch to the webview first
                const webviewName = `WEBVIEW_${packageName}`;
                **await driver.switchContext(webviewName);**
                // 2. Now we need to find the correct page inside the webview
                matchingContext = this.findMatchingContext({ contexts: currentContexts, identifier: packageName, title, url });
            }

            if (!matchingContext) {
                throw new Error(this.generateNonMatchingErrorMessage({
                    identifier: driver.isIOS ? BUNDLE_ID :
                    packageName as string,
                    title,
                    url,
                }));
            }

            // For iOS we can just use the `driver.switchContext` method to switch to the webview,
            // but for Android we are already in the webview. We now need to switch to the correct page inside the webview
            const switchFunction = driver.isIOS ? driver.switchContext.bind(driver) : driver.switchToWindow.bind(driver);
            // Now switch to the correct context
            return switchFunction(matchingContext.id);
        }

Reference project i took from github to webview automation:
https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate/blob/main/tests/helpers/WebView.ts
My error on Android 13 and 15 devices:
            [0-0] 2024-10-25T08:06:48.075Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND switchContext("WEBVIEW_com.example.app”)
            [0-0] 2024-10-25T08:06:48.075Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4445/session/f2afefe4-a523-454c-86ce-26cba6135245/context
            [0-0] 2024-10-25T08:06:48.075Z INFO webdriver: DATA { name: 'WEBVIEW_com.example.app' }
            [0-0] Error of test:  Error: waitUntil condition failed with the following reason: WebDriverError: This operation was aborted when running "context" with method "POST" and args "{"name":"WEBVIEW_com.example.app"}"  ]     at <anonymous> (/Users/vk/login/mobile-automation/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:4684:11)
            [0-0]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
            [0-0]     at async Browser.wrapCommandFn (/Users/vk/login/mobile-automation/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/index.js:1380:23)
            [0-0]     at async WebView.switchToContext (/Users/vk/login/mobile-automation/source/webview.ts:175:9)
            [0-0]     at async WebView.waitForWebsiteLoaded (/Users/vk/login/mobile-automation/source/webview.ts:320:9)
            [0-0]     at async UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/vk/login/mobile-automation/source/specs/tests//sign-in-test.spec.ts:40:13)
            [0-0]     at async UserContext.executeAsync (/Users/vk/login/mobile-automation/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/index.js:1500:20)
            [0-0]     at async UserContext.testFrameworkFnWrapper (/Users/vk/login/mobile/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/index.js:1571:14)


It sometimes happens that context name could be different on different devices and OS versions, I would try to log list retuned by this.getCurrentContexts() and check what is WebView name is actually there.
